# trying to update excel links but seeing a pop up box that doesn't make sense

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which creates links to other excel files. I use this link to update the links

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
```

but I get a weird pop up box for one of them even though none of the links reference this worksheet. Any ideas how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: You are asking what this means? it seems pretty clear to me that there is no sheet named "IML Checklist" in the file called "ZEL.xls" - And since you are using `ThisWorkbook` instead of qualified workbook objects, you are leaving it up to Excel to guess

Comment: I'm asking why this would be showing up or how to debug why it is showing up. None of the excel formula links my macro creates are referencing this worksheet name.

Comment: It's referenced in the ZEL.xls file somewhere, just not in your code.

Comment: @braX - `ThisWorkbook` *is* a qualified reference - it can only apply to one workbook: the one where the code is running.

Comment: You likely have a name which points to that sheet.  It doesn't need to be a worksheet formula.